# Global name 'number' is not defined on module import

Tags: python-2.7, import, module

I'm using python 2.7 on linux machine and I'm sure this is an obvious question but 
I really need this answer.

Module one named one in file **test**

```
def one():
     number=1
```

Module two named two in file **exam**

```
def two():
    if number == 1:
        print "apples and oranges"
```

and both of them imported into a container named **modi.py** like this

```
import test, exam

test.one()
exam.two()
```

I was hoping to set the variable "number" in module one and reference it in module two but I keep getting the name error **"global name 'number' is not defined"**

I just can't see the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is because number is in test.py.  Try adding `global number` before the first use in test.py and `import test` in exam.py.  Then use `if test.number == 1:`

Comment: thanks got it working with this http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules